# Command line for Application alias in Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, command-line

I’m working on an installer for a project and I’ve written a post-install script that runs the executable for my project after it’s done.

I want to know the command line argument—or if there is a way—to create an alias for the executable so that the alias will be put on my desktop instead of having to navigate to the folder it’s located in.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know the command line argument—or if there is a way—to
>   create an alias for the executable so that the alias will be put on my
>   desktop instead of having to navigate to the folder it’s located in.

Yes, you can. In the command line/terminal this is known as creating a symbolic link and this would be done using the [`ln`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ln.1.html) (make links) command. The general format is like this:

```
ln -s /path/to/source /path/to/destination/symlink
```

So in your case, you could do something like this:

```
ln -s /Applications/My_Great_Application.app ~/Desktop/My_Great_Application.app
```

Comment: Alias and symlink are technically not the same thing. A symlink will appear in the OS X UI as an alias, but creating an alias from the UI will not make a symlink. However, I think a symlink is the better solution.